# Use array value as variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use jQuery's keyup function to take the value from input html form elements and display said values in a div elsewhere.

The working code looks as follows:

```
$('#name').keyup(function() {
    var name = $(this).val();
    $('#name-in-document').html(name);
});
```

Since I have many identical instances of the above code block, I'd like to use a for loop to loop through an array of values. The catch is the name of the variable in the second line

```
var name = $(this).val();
```

would come from the array.

I have tried the following loop, which does not work because (as I understand it) a Javascript variable cannot be named an array value:

```
var inputsArray = ["phone", "name", "address"];

for (var i = 0; i < inputsArray.length; i++) {

    $("#"+inputsArray[i]).keyup(function() {

    var inputsArray[i] = $(this).val();
    $("#"+inputsArray[i]+"-in-document").html(inputsArray[i]);

    })
```

};

So I have two questions:

1. Is it true that I cannot use the array values to create a variable in the for loop?
2. Is there an alternate way to accomplish the same thing (getting the variable names from the array) that might work?

I am just beginning JavaScript and really appreciate any insight. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the alternative approach, I would recommend giving `#name` (and his friends) a class name, e.g.

```
<input class="js-key-up" id="name" />
```

Then you can do away with the array and the `for` loop altogether. Also, adding new HTML elements would not require adding items to the array.

**HTML**

```
<input class="js-key-up" id="phone">
<input class="js-key-up" id="name">
<input class="js-key-up" id="address">

<p id="phone-in-document"></p>
<p id="name-in-document"></p>
<p id="address-in-document"></p>
```

**JavaScript**
​

```
$('.js-key-up').keyup(function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + id + '-in-document').html($(this).val());
});​
```

I've [created a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47pZS/) with the code in.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** It is not true
**2.** You'll need to make a closure over the variable `i` or over the value from `inputArray[i]` and inside the event-bind the keyword `this` refers to the DOMNode witch triggers the event:

<sub>Read more absout closures here [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)</sub>

```
var inputsArray = ["phone", "name", "address"],
    i = 0,
    len = inputsArray.length;

for ( ; i < len; i ++ ) {
    makeKeyupBind(inputsArray[i]);
} 

function makeKeyupBind( value ) {
    $("#" + value).on("keyup", function() {
        $("#" + value + "-in-document").html( this.value );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That variable only exists within the scope of the function passed as a callback for the `keyup` event so I don't really see the need to give it a dynamic name; you could call it absolutely anything at all and not run into conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var inputsArray = ["phone", "name", "address"];

for (var i = 0; i < inputsArray.length; i++) {

    $("#"+inputsArray[i]).keyup(function() {

    var valuesArray[i] = $(this).val();
    $("#"+inputsArray[i]+"-in-document").html(valuesArray[i]);

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var inputsArray = ["phone", "name", "address"]; 
 for (var i = 0; i < inputsArray.length; i++) {
   $("#"+inputsArray[i]).keyup(function() {

   var htmlValue = $(this).val();
   $("#"+inputsArray[i]+"-in-document").html(htmlValue);
})
```

I think you don't need to name variable from array, do you?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a selector straight from the array and skip the loop completely. Use the id of the current input to create the selector for the other element

```
var inputsArray = ["phone", "name", "address"];

$('#'+ inputsArray.join(',#') ).keyup(){
   $('#'+this.id+"-in-document").html(  $(this).val() );
})
```

This will create the selector:

```
$('#phone,#name,#address')
```

Above assumes that you are trying to find elements :

```
 $("#phone-in-document").html(val);
   $("#name-in-document").html(val);/* etc*/
```

Answer (score 0):

@Wes Cossick: this line inside of the loop is wrong:

```
var valuesArray[i] = $(this).val();
```

if you want to do it that way declare the array before the loop. that is problem of OP

@diana: if i understand you correct, you want to add a dynamic keyup handler to every item in the array? if it is that way, that code should do it (dont reassign items in the array!) the trick is to create a closure (code is untested).

```
var inputsArray = ["phone", "name", "address"];

for (var i = 0; i < inputsArray.length; i++) {

  (function(item) {
    $("#"+item).keyup(function() {
      $("#"+item+"-in-document").html($(this).val());
    });
  })(inputsArray[i]);

};
```

if you are using jQuery (and it seems so ;-), take a look at the each-function in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

that should be a lot easier for you ;-)